# Is it necessary to use schema class while fetching the organization data?

Tags: salesforce-id

Is it possible to get oraganization data with out using the schema class.If it possible please provide me with one example

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of what you mean by "organization data"? What do you want to see? Are you working in Apex, or via the API?

Comment: Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = User.PG_SecretQuestionPick__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = F.getPicklistValues();

Comment: iam working on apex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the covers, you use Schema every day without realising it. You can't even insert a record without relying on Schema (hint: Account is actually Schema.Account).

It is possible, however, to access metadata without using Schema in Apex Code. This involves calling the REST API and using the describe calls, or a similar method. Andrew Fawcett's metadata API library uses a technique like this.

Please note, however, that this uses API calls, which are limited per 24 hour window, while Schema describe calls are free. You should only on consider this technique if Schema can't do what you need.

Comment: can u provide me any example program\